# Storing Hidden Value with Strongly Typed View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of moving from ASP.NET WebForms to MVC, and I have a question.

I have a strongly typed view. How would I go about storing an index of the item being deleted so that I can easily update the data if the page is submitted?

If I was using WebForms, I could either look at query arguments in the URL on postback, I could store the index in view data, or I could store it in a hidden control. How can I approach this in MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of MVC is that you can solve this several different ways.  You just need to find the solution that works best for your particular scenario.  While a hidden field will certainly work, it's not always the most ideal solution.  Here is a quick example delete scenario:

**Controller**

```
public class ExampleController
{
    static Dictionary<int, string> sampleViewModel = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {1, "Example Item 1"},
        {2, "Example Item 2"},
        {3, "Example Item 3"},
    };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(sampleViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        sampleViewModel.Remove(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>

<html>
   <head>
       ...
   </head>
   <body>
       <table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Item</th>
                   <th></th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               @foreach (var item in Model) {
               <tr>
                   <td>@item.Key</td>
                   <td>
                   @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", new { id = item.Value })) {
                       <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                   }
                   </td>
               </tr>
               }
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

I just threw this together quickly so my apologies for any syntactical errors.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. One additional question, if I may. If I'm trying to edit, do is there a way to access the updated model data? I'm having a heck of a time finding examples for this.

Comment: Absolutely.  You could do one of the following:
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

Comment: I'm trying that. But I'm still unsure how to access the model data being submitted.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was truncated.  Here's a better answer:
---
Absolutely.  Unfortunately there's not great way to answer that question in the comments here.  Check out the NerdDinner tutorial which does a good job introducing core MVC concepts:

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part5.htm

Note that this tutorial is a tad old and does not use the current version of MVC.  Still the concepts are the same.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was thinking there'd be something a bit more automated in MVC 3. But I seem to be able to get what I need, and can use `UpdateModel()` as a bit of a shortcut.